# is using atomic instead of thread thread-safe?

Tags: go

There is a parm which is read more and written less, And I don't want to use a mutex .I got it done like this by `unsafe` and `atomic`:

```
type tmp struct {
}
var value unsafe.Pointer 

func GetValue() *tmp {
    return (*tmp)(atomic.LoadPointer(&value))
}

func SetValue(p *tmp) {
    atomic.StorePointer(&value, unsafe.Pointer(p))
}
```

Is this thread-safe ? and atomic.StorePointer  `happen before` atomic.LoadPointer ?

Comment: Rule of thumb: Never use package unsafe, especially if you are unsure what you are doing.

Comment: @Volker in this case I think there is no way around it if you want to use `atomic`.

Answer (score 2):

It will be thread safe in the sense that you don't know what happens first, but the updating is atomic. Have you considered using a RWMutex instead? This won't lock readers unless there's a write going on.

Comment: I think the critical section is very short, just an assign-statement. The cost of using a Mutex or RWMutex is too much comparing to an assign-statement.I want to find a lock-free way.I think it is atomic but just don't know is there a `happen-before` relationship?

Comment: @buzz there is no synchronization between your load and store, so there is no "happens before" relationship.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, storing and retrieving a pointer using atomic.LoadPointer and atomic.StorePointer is thread-safe (in the sense that the pointer itself will not be corrupted).

Of course, the pointed object must be immutable, and this is not enforced by this mechanism. This is your job to be sure that updating the configuration will result in a new object being created before calling UpdateConfig.

However, the main issue is the code relies on unsafe operations. Making it type safe is difficult, since two pointers have actually to be stored (one for the object, one for the type). Atomic pointer operations are not enough anymore to guarantee the consistency.

This is why a specific type has been recently added in the sync/atomic package: [the sync.Value type](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#Value). It is designed exactly to do what you want (i.e. optimizing access to mostly constant data).

You can find an example here: http://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#example_Value_config

If you look in the [implementation](http://golang.org/src/sync/atomic/value.go), you will realize why atomic pointer operations alone are not enough to implement a type safe mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=5045

```
Regarding Add/CAS, it should be formulated in in more general terms, along the
lines of: at atomic operation that stores a value (incl ADD/CAS) happens before 
atomic operation that reads that value from the memory location (incl ADD/CAS).
```

I think We can use atomic to ensure it thread-safe.